# Who was the first person to use the phrase "fun fact"

Tags: etymology

I want to know when the first known use of the phrase *fun fact" was.

When, where, or who first used the phrase *fun fact* to mean a small tit-bit of information?

Comment: According to this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fun+fact&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfun%20fact%3B%2Cc0#), not later than 1888, apparently.

Comment: Perhaps (?) Daniel MacSweeney, "The Accountant's Guide; Or, A Complete System of Mercantile Arithmetic ... The Second Edition, Carefully Revised, Improved and Considerably Enlarged", 1809. https://www.google.nl/search?q=%22fun+fact%22&lr=lang_en&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1800%2Ccd_max%3A31%2F12%2F1844&tbm=bks

Comment: Or _maybe_ the first edition, of course. (1807?)

Comment: Nobody could be arsed to answer [Origin of the term “fun fact”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333745/origin-of-the-term-fun-fact) as posted several months ago, so I can't closevote as a duplicate. But it ***is***.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's been asked before

Comment: @FumbleFingers Could we bump the other question then because this has received three up-votes in half an hour; the question ought to be answered.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey: Well, it's obviously the same question, so if anyone looking at *this* page wants to answer they should be aware of the earlier post (which I don't recall closevoting, but I *might* have done; it doesn't strike me as particularly meaningful).