# If a fact is fun it is called Fun Fact. What if it is not?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

I am compiling a couple of facts to publish in a newsletter.

Some of them are fun to know so I've called them Fun Facts.

Some on the other hand are not-so-fun, even tragic in some cases. What is the right word to describe them?

Comment: Related: [Origin of the term "fun fact"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333745/origin-of-the-term-fun-fact).

Comment: I think the answer depends on why you're including these facts. If there's a specific reason, then the label should match that; if not, then they're "random facts".

Comment: The contrast can be found in 'cold hard facts' and 'inconvenient truths'.

Comment: “Fun Facts” and “Tragic Truths”.

Comment: It might be painful.

Comment: You can use whatever phrase you want. *Depressing Facts*, *Sad Facts*, *Boring Facts*, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The term "Fun fact" is really just a common *phrase* that consists of an adjective (fun) and a noun (fact). In other words, it is not a 'single word', and people can easily come up with another 2-word adjective+noun phrases, like "red apple", "green apple", "brown box", "white box". One could argue that the opposite of 'fun' can be either 'boring' or 'serious', but I think true opposites only come in pairs, such as in/out, up/down, ie, you can't have more than one opposite.

What I am trying to say therefore is, you can add any adjective in front of the word 'fact' to describe it, like sad/serious/tragic/funny fact, there doesn't have to be an opposite of a 'fun' fact.

Answer (score 1):

For a newsletter, you could use **General News** or **General Updates**. Those carry a neutral tone.

Comment: Neither of these works if they're historical facts though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the word *trivia* to represent all kinds of facts, whether they're fun or not. It's a fairly neutral term (regarding this aspect; it *does* convey a message that the facts aren't really useful to know).

> Details, considerations, or pieces of information of little importance or value.

<sub>(source: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trivia))</sub>